# Bounding the size of the product of a collection of sets

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Reading a proof from some book I came across to the following argument that I somehow don't understand fully. A clarification would be very nice.

Consider a collection $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of a set $S = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ such that $|A \cap B|$ is even for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}.$

Let $U,V$ be the set of incidence vectors of $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ from the space $\mathbb{F}_2^n.$ The incidence vector of a set being an $n$-vector with $1$ or $0$ in its $i$'th position if the element $x_i$ is in the set or not.

Now what the author does is it defines $V_0 = \{v + v_0 \mid v \in V\}$ for a fixed $v_0$ and lets $U',V_0'$ be the subspaces spanned by $U$ and $V_0$ respectively.  Then he argues

$$ |\mathcal{A} | \cdot |\mathcal{B}| = |U|\cdot |V| = |U| \cdot |V_0| \leq |U'|\cdot |V_0'| \leq 2^{\rm{dim}(U')+\rm{dim}(V_0')}$$

Since vectors from $U'$ and $V_0'$ are orthogonal to each other it is now possible to use the rank nullity theorem to bound the above product.

What I do not understand in this part of the argument is, why do we need to take $V_0$ and cannot just consider the subspace spanned by $V$?

Comment: Indeed, this seems unnecessary

Comment: Was this the actual statement being proved, or was it just a part of a larger proof? If the latter, could $V_0$ have been used somewhere further in the proof (e.g. because the dimension of $V'_0$ might have been easier to determine than that of $V$?)

Comment: @PeterKošinár That was basically it. The statement proved was that $|\mathcal{A}||\mathcal{B}| \leq 2^n$ which follows from what I wrote since $\rm{dim}(U')+\rm{dim}(V_0) \leq n.$ I don't see if this is somehow implied specifically by $V_0$ and not the space spanned by $V$